# overflow: visible for image in Wordpress Sidebar-Widget

Tags: css, wordpress, overflow

I am trying to get an image overflow in a Sidebar-Widget in Wordpress. It does work for *{overflow: hidden} but not if I do it with the classes. Can you help me?

This is the site an you will propably find the Image I mean: 
http://neuronade.com/kopie-sdfsdf-3

I tried:

```
.theme-page-wrapper mk-blog-single right-layout vc_row-fluid mk-grid .mk-builtin .sidebar-wrapper .widget widget_text .textwidget img{
```

overflow: visible !important;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the parent element is set to overflow:hidden.

`.widget {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 40px;}`

change the css for .widget class to overflow:visible.

or give the widet an id="xyz" and in style sheet set #xyz {overflow:visible !important;}

This is the parent element set to overflow:hidden:

section id="text-2" class="widget widget_text">

Answer (score 0):

Check your sidebar section under sidebar-wrapper class.
here you define

```
.widget {

    overflow: hidden;
}
```

remove this css.